# Replace special characters in a string (like "{ by { ) in R

Tags: r, special-characters, str-replace, stringr

I am stuck with replacing a series of special characters by another different series.

For instance, I have "{'request' and I want to change the starting "{ to {.

Here's one line of my data:

```
"{'request':{'id':'n98u4jiqp61c19v8eknicioq4be74pfe','time':'2017-08-21T21:57:27+00:00','type':'web','tcp':{'signature':{'attributes':{'ip_version':4,'initial_ttl':128,'options_length':0,'mss':1360,'window_size':'8192','window_scale':8,'options':'mss,nop,ws,nop,nop,sok','header_quirks':'df,id+'},'normalized_full':'34.2178821511','normalized_partial':'18.3082608836'},'mtu':{'type':'Probably IPsec or other VPN','size':1400},'ssl':{'protocol':'TLSv1.2','cipher':'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256','handshake':{'version':'3.3','ciphers':{'value':'aaaa,cca9,cca8,c02b,c02f,c02c,c030,c013,c014,9c,9d,2f,35,a','signature':{'value':'cca9,cca8,c02b,c02f,c02c,c030,c013,c014,9c,9d,2f,35,a','normalized':'13.552269047','garbage':['aaaa']}},'extensions':{'value':'dada,ff01,?0,17,23,d,5,12,10,b,a,baba','signature':{'value':'ff01,?0,17,23,d,5,12,10,b,a','normalized':'10.1792723498','garbage':['dada','baba']}},'flags':'ver,rtime'},'signature':{'normalized':'48.3888883277'}}},'network':{'rtt':{'value':84958,'variance':25927},'distance':27,'ip':{'address':'0.0.0.0','hostname':'0.0.0.0','asn':{'number':'AS2609','organization':'Tunisia BackBone AS'},'location':{'continent':{'code':'AF','name':'Africa'},'country':{'code':'TN','name':'Tunisia'},'city':{'name':'D'ile Deux'},'region':{'name':null},'timezone':{'name':'Africa\/Tunis','offset':-60},'coordinates':{'latitude':34,'longitude':9}}}},'header':{'structure':{'value':['Host','Connection','Content-Length','Origin','User-Agent','Content-type','Accept','Referer','Accept-Encoding','Accept-Language'],'leftover':['Content-Length','Origin','Content-type'],'normalized':'7.2362511174'},'languages':{'value':{'fr-FR':1,'fr':0.8,'en-US':0.6,'en':0.4},'normalized':'35.775591716'},'agent':{'string':'Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/60.0.3112.101 Safari\/537.36','os':{'name':'Windows','version':'10','platform':'x64','family':'Windows'},'client':{'type':'browser','name':'Chrome','version':'60.0.3112.101','engine':'Blink'},'device':{'type':'desktop','vendor':'','model':''}}},'context':{'source':'javascript-2.0','processor':'web-1.0','details':{'browser':{'features':['52','127','126','47','0','204'],'plugins':{'hash':'4.834303856','list':['widevinecdmadapter.dll 1481000','mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai','internal-nacl-plugin','internal-pdf-viewer']},'fonts':{'hash':'44.591879809','list':['Agency FB','Arabic Typesetting','Arial Black','Bauhaus 93','Bell MT','Bodoni MT','Bookman Old Style','Broadway','Calibri','Californian FB','Castellar','Centaur','Century Gothic','Colonna MT','Copperplate Gothic Light','Engravers MT','Forte','Franklin Gothic Heavy','French Script MT','Gabriola','Gigi','Goudy Old Style','Haettenschweiler','Harrington','Impact','Informal Roman','Lucida Bright','Lucida Fax','Magneto','Malgun Gothic','Matura MT Script Capitals','MingLiU-ExtB','MS Reference Sans Serif','Niagara Solid','Palace Script MT','Papyrus','Perpetua','Playbill','Rockwell','Segoe Print','Showcard Gothic','Snap ITC','Vladimir Script','Wide Latin']},'webgl':{'hashes':{'extensions':'25,1910689852','attributes':'3594354498','info':'1687665201'},'strings':{'attributes':'1,2,8,8,8,8,24,0,8,16384,32,16384,1024,16,16384,30,16,16,4096,1,1,1,1024,16384,16384,16,35633,35632','vendor':'GoogleInc.','renderer':'ANGLE(Intel(R)HDGraphicsDirect3D11vs_5_0ps_5_0)'}},'properties':{'name':'-1','platform':'Win32','concurrency':2,'flash_version':'0.0.0','math_vector':'2297712969','colors':'28,3846833241'},'navigator':'39,1102024947','languages':['fr'],'tokens':{'id':'20170821X4013172038Xn98u4jiqp61c19v8eknicioq4be74pfe'},'is_incognito':0,'history_length':3},'screen':{'width':1366,'height':768,'color_depth':24,'window_inner':'1366x662','window_outer':'1366x728','max_touch_points':'0','availwidth':1366,'availheight':728},'media':{'structure':'MMVSS','structure_list':['M741301070','M2957980628','V3222337076','S741301070','S3687074924'],'audio_signature':'18614.611131555066,172.67165302389913'},'battery':{'string':'A?,26','percentage':26,'status':'charging','status_seconds':0},'timezone':{'offset':1,'list':['-60','-60','-60']},'network':{'ipv4':['192.168.1.37'],'ipv6':['2001::9d38:6abd:3442:3626:3afa:f267'],'networks':['192.168.1']},'timing':{'dns_connection_ssl':1134,'latency':1134,'dns_resolution':72,'ssl_timing':974,'server_time':401,'content_download_time':177,'dom_timing':1623,'browser_process_time':1623,'event_binding_timing':0,'page_load':3183}}}},'identity':{'profile':'Chrome @ Windows @ TN','tag':{'id':'55e2dffc-8cb9-521b-98b2-526a68f603e4','fuzzy':'69d2f304-1795-5296-bd2a-9acdf4ad75c5','general':'35fc63aa-dd16-59b5-8932-d45255fd9117'},'recognized':{'fingerprints':{'passive':'18.3082608836\/48.3888883277\/7.2362511174\/35.775591716','context':'2.3300655535\/3.3983292286\/2.2957713582\/2.4102577126\/1.3430272718\/4.834303856\/44.591879809\/3.1275262912'},'os':[{'name':'Windows 7','signatures':5,'samples':66,'history':{'first_seen':1502198736,'last_seen':1503328113}},{'name':'Windows 10','signatures':5,'samples':45,'history':{'first_seen':1499346211,'last_seen':1503236236}},{'name':'Windows 8','signatures':5,'samples':34,'history':{'first_seen':1500265706,'last_seen':1503244946}}],'browser':[{'name':'Chrome','signatures':5,'samples':112,'history':{'first_seen':1496772867,'last_seen':1503244946}},{'name':'Opera','signatures':3,'samples':20,'history':{'first_seen':1499281234,'last_seen':1502415113}},{'name':'QQ Browser','signatures':2,'samples':4,'history':{'first_seen':1502916160,'last_seen':1502916411}},{'name':'Amigo','signatures':2,'samples':4,'history':{'first_seen':1502936943,'last_seen':1502937076}},{'name':'Sogou Explorer','signatures':2,'samples':6,'history':{'first_seen':1502525699,'last_seen':1502745114}}],'risk':[]}}}"
```

I was trying to use the str_replace from the stringr package, but I can't make it work with all those special characters in between.

I guess I need something like
str_replace(data, ""{", "{")

but it's not working

Any guess on how to change "{ with { for instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the special char `"` with a slash. So do this:

```
str_replace(data, "\"{", "{")
```

Comment: That's throwing me an error:  Error in stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
  Error in {min,max} interval. (U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL)

Comment: Hey @Fer, I am not sure what that error message means. I will suggest ask a new question and post your code there.